# MySQL query with condition from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to programming and MySQL and I think this is simple but not for me. So, I have two tables, Tickets and Ticket_user, and I need to get all the fields from the Table Ticket where user_id =15 and ticket_id >8.

Table 1 : Ticket

```
id             name          ...... other fields
7              Tickte1            
8              Tickte2  
9              ticket3
10             ticket4
11             Tickte5
```

Table 2 : Ticket_users

```
   id   ticket_id     User_id
   1     7             15           
   2     8             16
   3     9             15
   4     10            15
   5     11            8
```

Result:

```
  ticket_id     name          ...... other fields
  9             Tickte3             
  10             ticket4
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: and why 3 and 4 and not 1? what is the logic behind it?

Comment: I need to get tickets that have ticket_ids bigger than a specific tickeet_id I just choose number here to make it clear.

Comment: seems to be homework. Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into [JOIN CLAUSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

What your looking for is something like this

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Ticket t LEFT JOIN Ticket_users tu ON t.id = tu.ticket_id 
WHERE tu.user_id = 15 AND t.id > 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Both queries will work.

The second is faster if you have to handle a lot of data
First uses `IN` clause

```
SELECT 
    id, name
FROM
    Ticket
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
            ticket_id
        FROM
            Ticket_users
        WHERE
            User_id = 15 AND ticket_id > 7);
```

second uses `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    id, name
FROM
    Ticket t
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ticket_id
    FROM
        Ticket_users
    WHERE
        User_id = 15 AND ticket_id > 7) ut ON t.id = ut.ticket_id;
```